# Sharing data in dictionary between threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, dictionary

Assume code:

```
class Memory {
  Dictionary<int, int> m_values;
  Object lockObject = new Object();

  public int GetData(int key) {
    int result;
    lock (lockObject) {
      if (!m_values.TryGetValue(key, out result)) {
        result = VeryExpensiveComputationMethod(key);
        m_values[key] = result;
      }
    }
    return result
  }
}
```

This is safe but problem is that it is not very effective. Some idea how to do it better using .NET 2.0-compatible code? (in best scenario only threads waiting for same result for same keys should be waiting)

Comment: If you can upgrade to .NET4.0 and above you can take advantage of the Concurrent Collections, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent(v=vs.110).aspx such as a ConcurrentBag. this makes the code more elegant and readable. That in itself wont solve your problem, if you cant use a concurrent store I'd suggest using 2 different locks will mean the expensive method can execute outside of the locks.

Comment: I can't. I am using Unity 5.0 and it uses something from .NET 3.5 but not everything. No support for parts of .NET 4.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `ConcurrentDictionary` instead of a `Dictionary` you get two key improvements:

1. You don't need to bother with explicit locking
2. You have a (guaranteed to be observably atomic) `GetOrAdd` method that lets you get a value from the dictionary or add a value if one doesn't exist.

Combine that with use of `Lazy<T>`, which lets you create an object that defines its value as the result of an expensive computation that it ensures is run only once, run only when needed, and then cached and returned again and again if asked for the value repeatedly.

We can now create a `ConcurrentDictionary<int, Lazy<int>>`, and between these two types, it basically does all of our work for us:

Note that, once we get the `Lazy` returned from `GetOrAdd` it means that either:

1. it's a new lazy that hasn't even started computing the value, in which case it will compute the value and return it.
2. It's an existing lazy with an already computed value that can be returned immediately.
3. It's an existing lazy with a value that hasn't finished being computed; it'll wait until the operation finishes, and then that value will be returned to all of the calls waiting on its computation.

Under no circumstances will `VeryExpensiveComputationMethod` be called multiple times for the same key.

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<int, Lazy<int>> values =
    new ConcurrentDictionary<int, Lazy<int>>();

public int GetData(int key)
{
    //Note that this doesn't actually run VeryExpensiveComputationMethod 
    //until .Value is called on it
    var lazy = new Lazy<int>(() => VeryExpensiveComputationMethod(key));
    return values.GetOrAdd(key, lazy).Value;
}
```

---

As far as a .NET 2.0 solution, you don't have either type.  Using a `Dictionary` and locking is of course doable, just less clean:

```
private Dictionary<int, Lazy<int>> values;
private object sync = new object();
public int GetData(int key)
{
    Lazy<int> lazy;
    lock (sync)
    {
        if (!values.TryGetValue(key, out lazy))
        {
            lazy = new Lazy<int>(delegate
            {
                return VeryExpensiveComputationMethod(key);
            });
            values.Add(key, lazy);
        }
    }
    return lazy.Value;
}
```

As far as `Lazy`, you simply need to create your own version:

```
public delegate T Func<T>();
public class Lazy<T>
{
    private object key = new object();
    private Func<T> generator;
    private T value;
    public Lazy(Func<T> generator)
    {
        this.generator = generator;
    }

    private volatile bool hasComputedValue;
    public bool HasComputedValue { get { return hasComputedValue; } }

    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            lock (key)
            {
                if (HasComputedValue)
                    return value;
                else
                {
                    value = generator();
                    hasComputedValue = true;
                    generator = null;
                    return value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer for .NET 4.0+, but I think the question is for .NET 2.0...

Comment: @DanField Yeah, was in the process of writing a 2.0 version.

Comment: This is wat I needed ant it works perfectly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution given your .NET 2.0 constraint would be to keep a `Dictionary<int, object>` where you lookup the lock object for that key, and lock on that object. Thus your locking is more fine-grained and hence supports more concurrency. That said, you'd need another lock of some kind dealing with the case that you have a new unseen `int`.

Something like this:

```
internal class Memory
{
    public int GetData(int key)
    {
        int result;
        object locker;

        // short time lock, blocks all readers
        lock (lockObject)
            if (!m_locks.TryGetValue(key, out  locker))
            {
                locker = m_locks[key] = new object();
            }

        // long time lock, but only for readers of this key during expensive op
        lock (locker)
            if (!m_values.TryGetValue(key, out result))
            {
                result = m_values[key] = VeryExpensiveComputationMethod(key);
            }

        return result;
    }

    private readonly Object lockObject = new Object();
    private Dictionary<int, int> m_values;
    private Dictionary<int, object> m_locks;
}
```

Comment: looks like it means same task but locks but not for actual data :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by your comment. You have one lock object per dictionary entry; that satisfies your constraint that only readers of the same entry should block each other.

Comment: I meant that that let's call it locks-dictionary's content should be maintained as well and should be kept in sync with data-dictionary. In multithreaded environment.

Comment: I understand alex.b's comment to mean pretty much what your last sentence touches on - now you need another lock to protect your collection of locks, and that lock is potentially your new chokepoint.

Comment: It is a chokepoint, but it's held for a very short time. His implementation has a single chokepoint that's held for a very long time, blocking all dictionary activity. Anyway, as I said, mine's a simple solution; there are others.

Comment: Calling `TryGetValue` on the dictionary outside of the lock each time you do it is not safe.  You need to remove both of those checks.

Comment: @Servy - that's ok. If a value is returned, it *is* the right, one-and-only **locker** object for that value; the only way it got there was while **lockObject** was being held. If the "unsafe" value was null, we do a safe lookup, with a save set if necessary.

Comment: @Kit No, the call itself is entirely unsafe.  You're accessing a dictionary from multiple threads without any synchronization.  **That is not a safe operation**.  You cannot rely on it to work at all.  It *might* work, or it might return a nonsensical result, or it might throw an exception; any number of things could happen.  The check *needs* to be inside of the lock in both cases.

Comment: Dang. You're right. I reflected  the code. I'll update.

Comment: That's true **in a single threaded environment**.  When you call it while another thread is in the process of mutating the dictionary all bets are off.  If another thread is, say, adding a new value that results in a re-size of the backing array, any number of really bad things could happen, ranging from a bad value being returned to an index out of range exception.

Comment: You had several typos in the answer that I edited; feel free to check them and make sure they're in line with what you intended to write.

Comment: Thanks for your edits. Looks right now. FTR, double-checked lock is fine on something atomic (e.g. reading a boolean field). I was so used to it I forgot that `TryGetValue()` wasn't atomic.

Answer (score 0):

Pure .NET2.0 solution:

```
public delegate T Compute<T,TParameter>(TParameter parameter);

public sealed class Lazy<T,TParameter>
{
  private T m_Result;
  private volatile bool m_IsInitialized;
  private object m_SyncRoot = new object();
  private Compute<T,TParameter> m_Compute;
  private TParameter m_Context;

  public Lazy(Compute<T,TParameter> compute, TParameter context)
  {
    if (compute == null)
    {
      throw new ArgumentNullException("compute");
    }

    m_Compute = compute;
    m_Context = context;
  }

  public T Value
  {
    get
    {
      if (!m_IsInitialized)
      {
        lock (m_SyncRoot)
        {
          if (!m_IsInitialized)
          {
            m_Result = m_Compute.Invoke(m_Context);
            m_Compute = null;
            m_Context = default(TParameter);
            m_IsInitialized = true;
          }
        }
      }
      return m_Result;
    }
  }
}

class Memory
{
  static int VeryExpensiveComputationMethod(int key)
  {
    return key;
  }

  private Dictionary<int, Lazy<int,int>> m_Values = new Dictionary<int, Lazy<int,int>>();
  private object m_SyncRoot = new object();

  public int GetData(int key)
  {
    Lazy<int,int> result;
    lock (m_SyncRoot)
    {
      if (!m_Values.TryGetValue(key, out result))
      {
        result = new Lazy<int,int>(VeryExpensiveComputationMethod, key);
        m_Values[key] = result;
      }
    }
    return result.Value;
  }
}
```